# How to case and if become sql command

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

I have code that I want to become a SQL command.

My table `leavetabletest` has these columns:

```
Holiday, IsRestDay, mNP1, mNP2, mNP3, mNP4, mNP5
```

First I need to group by and then do the case and if

How to do it?

```
   Case Holiday='S'
        If IsRestDay
            mNP4_F8=mNP4_F8+Night_F8    
        Else
            mNP2_F8=mNP2_F8+Night_F8    
        Endif

   Case Holiday='L'
        IF IsRestDay
            mNP5_F8=mNP5_F8+Night_F8    
        Else
            mNP3_F8=mNP3_F8+Night_F8    
        Endif

   Other
        If IsRestDay
            mNP2_F8=mNP2_F8+Night_F8    
        Else
            mNP1_F8=mNP1_F8+Night_F8    
        Endif
```

I try to use case when, but it does not work

```
Select 
    sum(regular),
    case when holiday = 'S' and IsRestDay ='1' then sum(over_F8) end as    mOT6_F8
    case when holiday = 'S' and IsRestDay ='0' then sum(over_F8) end as mOT3_F8
    case when holiday = 'L' and IsRestDay ='1' then sum(over_F8) end as mOT5_F8
    case when  holiday = 'L' and IsRestDay ='0' then sum(over_F8) end as mOT4_F8
    case when holiday <> 'S' and holiday <> 'L' and IsRestDay ='1' then sum(over_F8) end as mOT2_F8
    case when holiday <> 'S' and holiday <> 'L' and IsRestDay ='0' then sum(over_F8) end as mOT1_F8
From 
    leavetabletest
group by 
    EmployeeID, DepartmentID, SectionID
```

Comment: your syntax is wrong. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql

Comment: this is not sql command.  It's VFP code...

Comment: then, please update the tag accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a sample of your data is hard to give you a complete answer, but based on your attempt you need to:

- separate each case statement by a comma;
- add `holiday` and `IsRestDay` to your group by;
- add `EmployeeID`, `DepartmentID` and `SectionID` to your select part (if that is what you need - not clear from the question).

It should look something like this:

```
Select EmployeeID
 , DepartmentID
 , SectionID 
 , sum(regular)
 , case when holiday = 'S' and IsRestDay ='1' then sum(over_F8) end as mOT6_F8
 , case when holiday = 'S' and IsRestDay ='0' then sum(over_F8) end as mOT3_F8
 , case when holiday = 'L' and IsRestDay ='1' then sum(over_F8) end as mOT5_F8
 , case when holiday = 'L' and IsRestDay ='0' then sum(over_F8) end as mOT4_F8
 , case when holiday <> 'S' and holiday <> 'L' and IsRestDay ='1' then sum(over_F8) end as mOT2_F8
 , case when holiday <> 'S' and holiday <> 'L' and IsRestDay ='0' then sum(over_F8) end as mOT1_F8
From leavetabletest
group by EmployeeID
 , DepartmentID
 , SectionID 
 , holiday
 , IsRestDay;
```